# Как получать данные о обновлении файла из кастомного сервиса?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

Всем примет. У меня есть сервис, который запускается в бродкаст ресивере по мере получения бродкаст ресивером данных, и выполняет запись данных в файл.
Далее, я хотел бы выводить данные из файла списком на главный экран, в мэйн активити. Однако, надо что бы данные по мере обновления файла обновлялись автоматически. Как мне это реализовать? Знаю, что надо коннектиться к сервису через IBinder, но как передавать данные немного не понимаю. Наверное надо какой то лиснер делать, помогите пожалуйста. Ниже код:

Мой биндер в сервисе.

```
override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder = bindService
    inner class BindService : Binder() {
        fun getService(): BroadcastService = this@BroadcastService
    }
```

Коннект к сервису из MainActivity:

```
val bindService = object: ServiceConnection {
            override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName?, service: IBinder?) {
                service as BroadcastService.BindService
                val a = service.getService()
                Log.i("FFFF", "YES")
            }

            override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        }

        bindService(Intent(this, BroadcastService::class.java), bindService, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
```

Получается, что биндер при старте активити один раз отрабатывает, а при дальнейшем срабатывании сервиса он уже не отрабатывает. Как сделать верно?

Comment: Сделай интент из сервиса и лови его в активити

Comment: В таком случае, в активити надо будет запускать цикл, который проверяет, пришел ли определенный интент. Это не то.

Comment: Вы плохо изучали интенты. Никакого цикла не надо. Она сам ловит интент. Вам только нужно поставить ресивер

Comment: Аа, а можете чуть подробнее? В каком место сервиса создать интент и как его передать в активити? Вопрос скорее всего глупый, но хотя бы наведите на мысль.

Comment: Судя по коду - у вас локальный биндинг и вы можете делать всё что угодно, вплоть до того что просто передать в сервис ссылку на активити или эземпляр слушателя и дёргать её методы после обновления (это просто взаимодействие двух классов). Но при дисконнекте нужно эту ссылку обнулять, чтобы не держать мёртвый объект в памяти. Другие способы взаимодействия с сервисом описаны в офф. гайде и где угодно: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаете в activity приёмник. В методе onCreate

```
BroadcastReceiver service1;

IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter();
filter1.addAction("SN_2_XR");
service1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("SN_2_XR")) {
        try {
            // здесь ваш код обработки сигнала
             _type_fuel_SN = intent.getStringExtra("type_fuel");
             _remaining_fuel_SN = intent.getIntExtra("ost_fuel", 0);
             _remaining_km_SN = intent.getStringExtra("ost_km");
             _task_SN = intent.getIntExtra("task", 0);
             _average_fuel_SN = (double) (intent.getIntExtra("sr_average", 0));
             } catch (NullPointerException e) {
             }
        }
    }
};
registerReceiver(service1, filter1);
```

И посылка интента из service. Пишите интент там, гже вы получили новые данные

```
static void send_can_pro(Context context) {
    Intent in2 = new Intent("SN_2_XR");
    in2.putExtra("sr_average", (int) (_sr_rashod_mainfuel*10));
    in2.putExtra("type_fuel", _type_fuel_main); 
    in2.putExtra("ost_km", _stock_vid); 
    in2.putExtra("ost_fuel", (int)_main_tank_res); 
    in2.putExtra("task", _event_now_MS); 
    context.sendBroadcast(in2);
}
```

Comment: onStartCommand вызывается один раз при старте сервиса, для инициализации. Оттуда вообще ничего посылаться не должно. Сделайте таймер в сервисе, например 5 минут. и туда поставьте отправку интента.
Если мой ответ помог, отметьте вопрос решённым

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял, как это работает. Есть еще вопросик. А если у меня броадкаст ресивер находится отдельно от активити, в классе BroadcastReceiver, как в таком случае передать данные в активити из ресивера?

Comment: ресивер должен находится в том активити или фрагменте или сервисе, где он будет обрабатывать то, что получил

Comment: у меня он вызывается из активити, но сам находится в отдельном классе. Это не верно?

Comment: Код бы увидеть, я в описаниях всего и вся путаюсь, больше практик. Главное что бы работало. А это вы увидите сразу )

Comment: Это мой ресивер. Он в отдельном классе. А вызывается ресивер из активити.
class EventReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (!intent.action.equals("FILE_UPDATED")){
            context.startService(Intent(context, BroadcastService::class.java).putExtra(INTENT_TAG, intent.action))
        }else if (intent.action.equals("FILE_UPDATED")){
                Log.i("FFFF", "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        }
    }
}
Тут ужасно конечно отображается код...

Comment: Не городите лишнего. Поставьте ресивер в onCreate, а дальше отправляйте полученные данные куда хотите

Comment: Хорошо, а в таком случае, будет ли ресивер работать в бэкграунде, если я закрою приложение? В данный момент, при закрытом приложении у меня работает сервис и ресивер ловит события. Если в активити его перенесу, не будет ли ресивер удалён, когда я закрою приложение?

Comment: да, будет закрыт. Но пока он на экране, он будет работать. А если нужно в фоне, это нужен сервис

Comment: Дак есть сервис, и они в тандеме работают с этим ресивером, который сейчас у меня) Но проблема в том, что когда приходит экшн в ресивер, мне надо сразу сообщить активити, что событие пришло. Если это делать вашим способом, то это легко реализуется, но не будет работать, если активити уничтожится. Если моим способом, то я не знаю, как передать из ресивера в активити.

Comment: Проверил сейчас. Уничтожаю активити, ресивер остается работать. Меня это устраивает. Спасибо за помощь :)